# Calculate distance between points using gdist() for grouped subsets

Tags: r, group-by, gps, dplyr

A subset of my data for 2 individuals (`squirrelID`) can be found [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d).

My data looks as follows (only showing the relevant columns):

```
lat                  lon                NatalMidden   squirrelID    type
60.9577819984406    -138.0347849708050  -27           NA            Nest2017
60.9574120212346    -138.0345689691600  -27           NA            NatalMidden
60.9578209742904    -138.0346520338210  -27           23054         Foray
60.9575380012393    -138.0348329991100  -27           23054         Foray
60.9576250053942    -138.0339069664480  -27           23054         Foray
60.957643026486     -138.0338829942050  -27           23054         Foray
60.9575670026243    -138.0348739866170  -27           23054         Foray
```

For example, for `squirrelID` 23054, it was located (`Foray`) multiple times (`type` column) and I have a corresponding latitude (`lat`) and longitude (`lon`) for each `Foray`. I am trying to calculate the distance between each `Foray` (`type` column) and `Nest2017` (`type` column) for each individual (`squirrelID`) separately.

The below code works (and gives me a value of 15.11501 m), but it requires that I manually enter each point. This is not problematic, per say, but I am working with +2000 observations with more than 2 options per `grid`, `NatalMidden`, and `squirrelID` columns.

```
library(Imap)

gdist(60.9578209742904,-138.0346520338210, 60.9577819984406, -138.0347849708050, units="m", verbose=FALSE)
```

**Is there a way I could work within the** `dplyr` **framework to** `group_by(squirrelID)` **and then calculate the distances between each** `Foray` **and its corresponding** `Nest2017` **(which has the same** `NatalMidden` **for both the** `Foray` **and** `Nest2017`**)?**

My ultimate goal is to create a new column for the distance between the `Foray` and `Nest2017` for each `squirrelID`.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following:

```
nests<-df %>% #creating a new data frame for Nest2017 points only
    filter(type %in% "Nest2017") %>%
    select(ID,lat,lon,ele,grid,NatalMidden,type)

foray<-df %>% #creating a new data frame for Foray points only
    filter(type %in% "Foray") %>%
    mutate(sq_id=as.factor(sq_id)) %>%
    group_by(sq_id)
```

But these subsets do not work in the `gdist` function (I get this error):

```
gdist(nests$lat, nests$lon, foray$lat, foray$lon, units="m", verbose=FALSE)

Error in while (abs(lamda - lamda.old) > 1e-11) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(lon.1, rad) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(lat.1, rad) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(lon.2, rad) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(lat.2, rad) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
5: In lon.1 - lon.2 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
6: In while (abs(lamda - lamda.old) > 1e-11) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: There are two "Nest2017" values in the linked dataset. Assuming the correspondence is via the 'grid' column, why not `subset` the data frame once `type == "Foray"` and another `type == "Nest2017"` and `merge` the two `by = "grid"`,then simply `apply` your calculation to each row? I am missing how grouping by 'squirrelID' would help..

Comment: @dojuba Yes, but there are 35 `Nest2017` values in my real dataset, of which I linked a dataset with 2 `Nest2017` values for simplicity. The `grid` column is shared by multiple different `Nest2017` values. I might be missing what you mean though. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the distance for all possible combinations of "Foray" rows and "Nest2017" rows? In other words, if there are 35 different "Nest2017" values in your dataset, do you want to calculate 35 different distances for a given row where type is "Foray" independent of what the "grid" value is?

Comment: @dojuba For each `squirrelID`, they have multiple `foray` rows and only 1 `Nest2017` (out of the 35). So, I want to calculate the distance between each `foray` row for that specific `squirrelID` and the 1 `Nest2017` location that corresponds to that specific `squirrelID`. And then I would need to do that for ~70 `squirrelID`'s.

Comment: maybe I am missing something here, but neither in the small set above nor in the larger one in the link, any "Nest2017" rows have a numeric value in the "squirrelID" column, only `NA`s.

Comment: @dojuba That is correct. The way I need to connect the `squirrelID` to the `Nest2017` row is using the `NatalMidden` column since  `squirrelID`'s and   `Nest2017`'s have a shared `NatalMidden` id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with `dplyr` package but I think this would do what you are interested in:

```
# read data from the FigShare linked file
squirrel_data <- read.table("figshare.txt", header=T)

# split into 'Forays' and 'Nests'
nests <- squirrel_data %>%
  filter(type %in% "Nest2017")
foray <- squirrel_data %>%
  filter(type %in% "Foray")

# merge 'Forays' and 'Nests' by 'NatalMidden'
nests_foray <- inner_join(
  nests, foray, by = "NatalMidden", suffix = c(".nest", ".foray"))

# calculate the distance for each row, keep 'SquirrelID' and 'Dist'
results <- nests_foray %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dist = gdist(lat.nest, lon.nest,
                      lat.foray, lon.foray, units = "m")) %>%
  select(squirrelID.foray, dist)
head(results, n = 3)
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  squirrelID.foray     dist
#             <int>    <dbl>
#1            22684 14.03843
#2            22684 59.06996
#3            22684 13.40567
```

This is basically what I have proposed in my first comment, but using `dplyr` functions instead of `base`. The idea is simply to create inner join between "Foray" rows and "Nest2017" rows by "NatalMidded", then simply calculate the distance for each row and report it with "SquirrelID". I hope this helps.

Comment: I had to change how I imported the data (I imported it as a csv and that was giving me errors), but once I imported it as a txt file it worked! Thank you for helping.